# Photoshop expand folder keyboard shortcut

Tags: photoshop, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the Photoshop keyboard shortcut to expand a folder?

For example, I'd like to use my keyboard to expand the selected "yellow" folder:

[image]

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: This is more of a superuser.com type question I think.  That site is for these exact sorts of questions about program details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can.  If you go to Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts, there is nothing in the Application or Panels menus to expand/contract a group.